# GroupLevelIndicatorPane causes ColumnStretchMode=ALL to not fit columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I have an Xceed datagrid that uses ColumnStretchMode=ALL to make the columns fit in the grid.

It has been working perfectly, until I added a GroupLevelIndicatorPane.  Once I added that, the grid no longer fits right (it is off by the width of the GroupLevelIndicatorWidth amount).

I have been looking for a way to cause this calculation to take that pane into account with out any luck.

**Has anyone else ever seen this with the Xceed controls?**  (I don't have current Xceed support so they will not help me.)

UPDATE:
I found out why this was happening.  I had something to this effect in my grid setup:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:GroupLevelIndicatorPane}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding RelativeSource=
           {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}},
           Path=DataContext.ShouldIndent, Converter=
           {StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" />       
</Style>
```

I caused the GroupLevelIndicatorPane to be collapsed for some types of groups.  I took it out and the calculations started working right again.

Guess I need to find another way to have some groups not indent.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to apply the visibility on the actual GroupLevelIndicatorPane (not on the style).  Once I did that the ColumnStretchMode=ALL calculated correctly.

Not sure why it matters, but it does.